# PayPal REST API - Moving from Sandbox to Production

Tags: api, rest, paypal, live

I am using the PayPal .Net SDK (got it from github) in my Asp.Net MVC5 web application. Everything worked well while testing in the sandbox environment. Everything is stored in the web.config file:

```
<settings>
  <add name="mode" value="sandbox"/>
  <add name="connectionTimeout" value="360000"/>
  <add name="requestRetries" value="1"/>
  <add name="clientId" value="my rest app sandbox client id"/>
  <add name="clientSecret" value="my rest app sandbox client secret" />
</settings>
```

What I have done for going live is getting the live credentials of the REST App from the paypal developer portal. I then chnaged the web.config settings to:

```
<settings>
  <add name="mode" value="live"/>
  <add name="connectionTimeout" value="360000"/>
  <add name="requestRetries" value="1"/>
  <add name="clientId" value="my rest app live client id"/>
  <add name="clientSecret" value="my rest app live client secret" />
</settings>
```

When I run my web application in the live mode, it fails when calling the oAuth token generation:

```
string clientRequestsToken = payPalTAuthToken.GetAccessToken();
```

I am getting an IdentityException while the line of code above is executed.

Am I missing something ? do I need to configure anything else for going live with the PayPal REST APIs ?

I have read that when using the Classic APIs, a certificate needs to be generated and installed on the consumer server to encrypt the credentials, but I would assume this is only relevant for the Classic APIs, not for the REST APIs.

Thx for your help !

Sam

Answer (score 2):

You could find information about moving from sandbox to live over here:

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-do-i-target-the-live-or-sandbox-paypal-services

We are adding more and more FAQs to help developers resolve issues faster. Let us know, or update yourself, if you have any FAQ, that you want answered, or help us answer.